# User '/reference' instead of '/docs' for the docs plugin

Tags: docusaurus

Is it possible to to use `http://localhost:3000/reference/` or any other path instead of `http://localhost:3000/docs/` to point to the documentation `*.md` structure?

I configured the `preset-classic` inside `docusaurus.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          path: 'reference/',
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./reference/sidebars.js')
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

but I get:

```
test.md 1:2
Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> ---
| id: test
| title: Test
 @ ./.docusaurus/registry.js 1:2593-2646 1:2459-2559
...
```

I'm using Docusaurus V2, does it currently support this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Your mistake was probably the `/` in `path: 'reference/',`.

**Note:** When you change the `docusaurus.config.js` you need to kill the docusaurus process and start again, it doesn't reload well --- at least not with me.

```
[...]
presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          routeBasePath: 'reference',
          path: 'reference',
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./reference/sidebars.js'),
          lastVersion: 'current',
          onlyIncludeVersions: ['current'],
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
[...]
```

You probably will need to change the `navbar`.

```
[...]
navbar: {
  [...]
  items: [
    {
      to: '/reference',
      label: 'Reference',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/reference/`,
    },
  ],
},
[...]
```